# solving a galois field matrix equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, galois-field

I have the equation `AX * C = AXB` where all of the variables are square gf matrices of size n and the values are 0 or 1. AXB and AX are known, while C should be solved to B or an equivalent of it (there should be multiple solutions). Because X most likely isn´t regular (rank < n) not all of the variables in C can be calculated and i have to guess the rest after solving.

Question is: Can Matlab solve this equation (as far as possible), and in a better way than "manually" splitting the equation into n^2 equations?

I already tried to tell matlab that C is a symbol of, let´s say [8,8] and to solve `AX*C==AXB`, but solve doesn´t seem to work with galois fields.

Any hints on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you want to use symbolic math for this. Do you have the [Communications System](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/index.html) toolbox? If so, then you should be able to use [`gf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/gf.html) and [`gf/mldivide`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/mldivide.html).

Comment: i guess i do have the comm sys Toolbox, but it still doesn´t work with: `C = AX\AXB` - Error in gf/usolve: Input Matrix must be nonsingular. I tried that with a 5x5 matrix while the ranks of AX and AXB where 4